# Summarizing Deadline Dates on an Excel Spreadsheet

Tags: excel, calendar, scheduling, summary, worksheet

I have created a table in Excel. The format is "Table Style Light 3.

The table extends from E9 to AJ22.

The top row shows dates from "Wednesday, June 1, 2022" to "Thursday, June 30, 2020." These extend from G9 to AJ9.

Primary duties are listed from E11 to E22. Some of these cells are blank. Others are filled with text- no numbers.

Secondary duties are in cells F11 to F22. Some of these cells are blank, Others are filled with text- no numbers.

Cells in G10 to AJ22 are filled with color- no text and no numbers. Begin dates are solid green. Interim work-days are two-color diagonal gradient colored. Deadlines are solid yellow.

Cells before begin dates have no text, numbers, or fill colors. Cells after deadlines have no text, numbers, or fill colors.

I want to create a different worksheet that lists the Primary and Secondary duties which correspond to the solid yellow cells of the corresponding (same) row.

Please list steps and explanations with limited jargon as I am barely moderately proficient with Excel. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Do the solid yellow cells contain a value (a number or text), or are they just coloured yellow using the colour picker in excel?

Comment: this does not appear to be a question related to programming

Comment: @A. Steer, The solid yellow cells contain no values. They are coloured yellow using the color picker. Thank you :)